# Bin dates without aggregation in Pandas

Tags: date, pandas

I have a date column in a `Pandas.DataFrame`:

```
date             Value        
2014-02-27           0        
2014-08-15           1        
2015-04-11           1        
2014-09-01           2
```

I need a function to create a new column that identifies what quarter, month, etc. a record belongs to as shown below:

```
get_date_bucket(date_var='date', frequency='Q')

date             Value        date_bucket
2014-02-27           0         2014-03-31
2014-08-15           1         2014-09-30
2015-04-11           1         2015-06-30
2014-09-01           2         2014-09-30
```

or...

```
get_date_bucket(date_var='date', frequency='M')

date             Value        date_bucket
2014-02-27           0         2014-02-29
2014-08-15           1         2014-08-31
2015-04-11           1         2015-04-30
2014-09-01           2         2014-09-30
```

The data is reasonably large and I don't want to do any aggregation if I can avoid it.  What is the simplest way to create the 'date_bucket' column from the 'date' column on the left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easiest way is using a `pd.offset`

```
df['date_bucket'] = df.date + pd.offsets.QuarterEnd()
df
```

[image]

---

To generalize to any frequency specified by a string

```
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset

df.date + to_offset('Q')
```

Comment: I should have mentioned this (adding now) but I need to be able to specify the frequency ('Q', 'M', 'D', etc.)

Comment: @Chris I'm not clear as to what you want.  This is why it's important to be unambiguous.  Do you want multiple columns?  One with quarter end, another with month end?  Do you want the option?

Comment: Sorry.  I want to return just one column, but I want the bucket frequency to be something that the user can specify with a string.